# Gatling. Check, if a HTML result contains some string

Tags: scala, gatling

Programming Gatling performance test I need to check, if the HTML returned from server contains a predefined string. If it does, break the test with an error.

I did not find out how to do it. It must be something like this:

```
  val scn = scenario("CheckAccess")
    .exec(http("request_0")
      .get("/")
      .headers(headers_0)
      .check(css("h1").contains("Access denied")).breakOnFailure()
      )
```

I called the wished function "contains" and "breakOnFailure" in the example above. Does Gatling have something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better solutions:

with one single CSS selector:

```
.check(css("h1:contains('Access denied')").notExists)
```

with substring:

```
.check(substring("Access denied").notExists)
```

Note: if what you're looking for only occurs at one place in your response payload, substring is sure more efficient, as it doesn't have to parse it into a DOM.

Comment: Is it possible to perform this check after a post? I'm able to chain this check to a "get" but not to a "post"... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here ist the solution

```
.check(css("h1").transform((s: String) => s.indexOf("Access denied"))
.greaterThan(-1)).exitHereIfFailed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it very simple like:

```
.check(css("h1", "Access denied").notExists)
```

If you are not sure about H1 you can use:

```
.check(substring("Access denied").notExists)
```

IMO server should respond with proper status, thus:

```
.check(status.not(403))
```

Enjoy and see http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_check.html for details

EDIT:
My usage of CSS selector is wrong see Stephane Landelle solution with CSS.
I'm using substring way most of the time :)

Comment: css("h1", "Access denied") looks for an attribute "Access denied" inside the h1 tag.