# Check string in gatling simulation

Tags: scala, gatling

Trying to check if a string exists on the body. Similar to checking status which is `.check(status.is(200))`.  I want to check for string as well.  tried `.check(bodyString.is("greeting"))` but got an error:

```
val scn = scenario("GreetingPages")
.during(testTimeSecs) {
  exec(
    http ("greeting")
      .get("/greeting")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(bodyString.is("Greeting"))
  ).pause(minWaitMs,maxWaitMs)
  .exec(
    http("greeting1")
      .get("/greeting1")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(bodyString.is("Greeting1"))
  ).pause(minWaitMs,maxWaitMs)
  .exec(
    http("Third page")
      .get("/greeting2")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(bodyString.is("Greeting2"))
  ).pause(minWaitMs,maxWaitMs)

}
```

---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------

> bodyString.find.is(Greeting), but actually found {"message":"G      9 (47.37%)
>   reeting"}
>   bodyString.find.is(Greeting1), but actually found {"message":"      5 (26.32%)
>   Greeting1"}
>   bodyString.find.is(Greeting2), but actually found {"message":"      5 (26.32%)
>   Greeting2"}

Comment: Have you  checked this answer? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596668/gatling-check-if-a-html-result-contains-some-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596668/gatling-check-if-a-html-result-contains-some-string) Something like this should work: `.check(substring("greeting").exists)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the `bodyString` return the full response body, as it described in the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/2.2/http/http_check/).

You could use `in` matcher (you can see the implementation [here - look for InMatcher[A]](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/bda6c0bc545cc4375a589b4b46c00e3dc13b6d84/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/check/Validator.scala), but it won't work because you need to switch `expected.contains(actualValue)` with `expected.contains(expected)`

I suggest you implement your own `MyOwnInMatcher`:

```
class MyOwnInMatcher[A](expected: Seq[A]) extends Matcher[A] {

  def name: String = "customIn"

  protected def doMatch(actual: Option[A]): Validation[Option[A]] = actual match {
    case Some(actualValue) =>
      if (expected.contains(actualValue))
        actual.success
      else
        s"found $actualValue".failure
    case _ => Validator.FoundNothingFailure
  }
}
```

and use it:

`.check(jsonPath("$.message").validate(customIn("Greeting"))))`, which checks if "Greeting" exists in the `message` attribute of the json response body.